# How to shortern numpy code used for extraction

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am writing 29 lines of extraction codes for my data extraction. Is there anyway I can shorten my code?

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.recfunctions import append_fields
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_y = np.genfromtxt('data/housing-and-development-board-resale-price-index-1q2009-100-quarterly.csv',
                       names=True,
                       dtype=None,
                       delimiter=",",
                       missing_values='na,-',
                       filling_values=-1,
                       encoding=None)
# check if data load correctly
print(data_y)
years = []
for quarter in data_y['quarter']:
    year, q = quarter.split('-') # the new column name is year
    years.append(int(year))
years = np.array(years)
data_y = append_fields(data_y, 'year', years)

print(data_y)

# is there a way to make the following of 29 extractions more elegant?
data_1990 = data_y[data_y['year']==1990]
data_1991 = data_y[data_y['year']==1991]
data_1992 = data_y[data_y['year']==1992]
data_1993 = data_y[data_y['year']==1993]
data_1994 = data_y[data_y['year']==1994]
data_1995 = data_y[data_y['year']==1995]
data_1996 = data_y[data_y['year']==1996]
data_1997 = data_y[data_y['year']==1997]
data_1998 = data_y[data_y['year']==1998]
data_1999 = data_y[data_y['year']==1999]
data_2000 = data_y[data_y['year']==2000]
data_2001 = data_y[data_y['year']==2001]
data_2002 = data_y[data_y['year']==2002]
data_2003 = data_y[data_y['year']==2003]
data_2004 = data_y[data_y['year']==2004]
data_2005 = data_y[data_y['year']==2005]
data_2006 = data_y[data_y['year']==2006]
data_2007 = data_y[data_y['year']==2007]
data_2008 = data_y[data_y['year']==2008]
data_2009 = data_y[data_y['year']==2009]
data_2010 = data_y[data_y['year']==2010]
data_2011 = data_y[data_y['year']==2011]
data_2012 = data_y[data_y['year']==2012]
data_2013 = data_y[data_y['year']==2013]
data_2014 = data_y[data_y['year']==2014]
data_2015 = data_y[data_y['year']==2015]
data_2016 = data_y[data_y['year']==2016]
data_2017 = data_y[data_y['year']==2017]
data_2018 = data_y[data_y['year']==2018]
# is there a way to make the following of 29 extractions more elegant?
data_90 = data_1990['index']
data_91 = data_1991['index']
data_92 = data_1992['index']
data_93 = data_1993['index']
data_94 = data_1994['index']
data_95 = data_1995['index']
data_96 = data_1996['index']
data_97 = data_1997['index']
data_98 = data_1998['index']
data_99 = data_1999['index']
data_00 = data_2000['index']
data_01 = data_2001['index']
data_02 = data_2002['index']
data_03 = data_2003['index']
data_04 = data_2004['index']
data_05 = data_2005['index']
data_06 = data_2006['index']
data_07 = data_2007['index']
data_08 = data_2008['index']
data_09 = data_2009['index']
data_10 = data_2010['index']
data_11 = data_2011['index']
data_12 = data_2012['index']
data_13 = data_2013['index']
data_14 = data_2014['index']
data_15 = data_2015['index']
data_16 = data_2016['index']
data_17 = data_2017['index']
data_18 = data_2018['index']

data_combined = np.empty([len(year), 29])

for i in range(len(data_90)):
    data_combined[i] = np.array([data_90[i], data_91[i], data_92[i], data_93[i], data_94[i], data_95[i], data_96[i],
                                 data_97[i], data_98[i], data_99[i], data_00[i], data_01[i], data_02[i], data_03[i],
                                 data_04[i], data_05[i], data_06[i], data_07[i], data_08[i], data_09[i], data_10[i],
                                 data_11[i], data_12[i], data_13[i], data_14[i], data_15[i], data_16[i], data_17[i],
                                 data_18[i]])
# is there a way to make the following of 29 extractions of labels more elegant?
labels = np.array(['1990', '1991', '1992', '1993', '1994', '1995', '1996', '1997', '1998', '1999', '2000', '2001',
                   '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', ' 2011', '2012', '2013',
                   '2014', '2015', '2016', '2017', '2018'])

boxprops = dict(linestyle='-', linewidth=2, color='blue')
flierprops = dict(marker='o', markerfacecolor='green', markersize=8)
medianprops = dict(linewidth=2, color='red')

plt.figure(figsize=(60, 60))
plt.title('Movement of Resale Price Index (RPI)', fontsize=15, weight='bold')
plt.boxplot(data_combined, labels=labels, flierprops=flierprops, medianprops=medianprops, boxprops=boxprops)
plt.ylabel('Resale Price Index (RPI)', labelpad=20, fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('Years', labelpad=20, fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

Comment: It is useful to know the data come from https://data.gov.sg/dataset/hdb-resale-price-index?resource_id=52e93430-01b7-4de0-80df-bc83d0afed40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
year_data = {year: data_y[data_y['year']==year] for year in np.unique(data_y['year'])}
```

Comment: Appreciate your reply, tried changing to the the recommended code, but got an error. Also, I plan not to include the data of year 2019.

year_data = {year: data_y[data_y['year']==year] for year in data_y['year'].unique()}
print (year_data)
rpi_data = {year: data_y[data_y['index']==index] for index in data_y['index'].unique()}

i get an error:
 year_data = {year: data_y[data_y['year']==year] for year in data_y['year'].unique()}
AttributeError: 'MaskedArray' object has no attribute 'unique'

Comment: @Breathe: There was a bug there (I used Pandas syntax instead of NumPy).  Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

## Easiest with Pandas

Using Pandas your code becomes much, much shorter.

```
import pandas

filename = 'data/housing-and-development-board-resale-price-index-1q2009-100-quarterly.csv'
df = pandas.read_csv(filename, parse_dates=['quarter'])

df['year'] = df.quarter.dt.year

df.boxplot('index', by='year')
```

Results in the boxplot you want without the formatting. You can of course set all the things you did before and get it looking exactly the same as well. Note that you then have to pass the `ax` parameter to `boxplot`.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(60, 60))
df.boxplot('index', by='year', ax=plt.gca())
plt.title('Movement of Resale Price Index (RPI)', fontsize=15, weight='bold')
plt.boxplot(data_combined, labels=labels, flierprops=flierprops, medianprops=medianprops, boxprops=boxprops)
plt.ylabel('Resale Price Index (RPI)', labelpad=20, fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('Years', labelpad=20, fontsize=12)
```

## Without Pandas

If you cannot use pandas for some reason, you can build your data much more simply like this:

```
labels = sorted(set(years))
data_combined = [data_y[data_y['year'] == i]['index'] for i in labels]
```

These two lines replace everything in your code between `print(data_y)` and `boxprops = ...`.

Comment: Hi appreciate your reply, but my assignment only allow me to use numpy and matplotlib., using others modules would fail the question.

Comment: @Breathe OK, I've added a simplification of your building code without pandas.